# Create <div> with single element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anchor

I have this AJAX request:

```js
function getLocation() {
    $.get('../class/info/act/all', function (locations) {
        window.locations = locations;
        var key = ["id", "name", "nodelist"];
        for(var l = 0; l < locations.length; l++) {
            var roomValue = {};
            roomValue = locations[l];
            var span = document.createElement("div");

            for (var p = 0; p < key.length; p++) {
                if(locations[l]){
                    var anchor = document.createElement('a');
                    anchor.classList.add("content" + l);
                    span.append(anchor);
                    var textContent = document.createTextNode(roomValue[key[p]]);
                    anchor.append(textContent);
                    $(".roomContent").append(span);
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```

```html
<div id="inner" class="roomContent">
    </div>
```

```
After the request is done, the div is populated like this:

<div>
<a class=""content0">1</a>
<a class=""content0">ROOM1</a>
<a class=""content0">1,2</a></div>
```

What I want is a single element containing all the info, something like this:

```
<div>
<a class=""content0">1 ROOM1 1,2</a></div>
```

Any ideas? Is there a way to split the info? I searched for a clue but I didn't find anything

Comment: Move `var anchor = document.createElement('a');` outside loop

Comment: @Satpal thanks man. It worked, i was thinking more complex but the solution was already there

Comment: Here's jQuery code: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/7ew23csh/

Answer (score 0):

add outside forloop: `var span = document.createElement("div");
var anchor = document.createElement('a');
anchor.classList.add("content" + 0);
span.append(anchor);`

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create and apend the anchor outside of your for cycle, so it actually does it only once.

```
function getLocation() {
$.get('../class/info/act/all', function (locations) {

    if(locations.length === 0) { //do nothing if there's nothing to do
        return;
    }
    window.locations = locations; //window shouldn't be used to store unnecessary non-global variables, use correct scope

    var key = ["id", "name", "nodelist"];

    //prepare elements
    var anchor = document.createElement('a'); 
    var span = document.createElement("div");

    //fill with values, set classes
    for(var l = 0; l < locations.length; l++) {
        var roomValue = {};
        roomValue = locations[l];

        for (var p = 0; p < key.length; p++) {
            if(locations[l]){ //this is unnecessary as it is always true - you're already iterating through the array                   
                anchor.classList.add("content" + l);                    
                var textContent = document.createTextNode(roomValue[key[p]]);
                anchor.append(textContent);
            }
        }           
    }

    //append prepared elements
    span.append(anchor);
    $(".roomContent").append(span);
})
```

}